# Filter a row in a csv file in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, csv, row

I'm new to javascript, and I'm trying to just get one row from unique id column from a large csv file. How would I go about doing that? I found an example here http://www.activewidgets.com/javascript.forum.25996.1/filter-rows-in-csv-file.html

```
function filter(text, column){ 
    var i, rows = [], max = table.getCount();
    if (text==''){ 
    obj.setRowCount(max); 
    obj.setRowIndices(''); 
    } 
    if (text !=''){ 
        for (i=0; i<max; i++){ 
            if (obj.getCellValue("column", i).indexOf(text)> -1 ){ 
                rows.push(i); 
            } 
        } 
    obj.setRowCount(rows.length); 
    obj.setRowIndices(rows); 
    } 
obj.getRowsTemplate().refresh(); 
}
```

but I'm not sure if the csv file is automatically a table, and where should I indicate which csv file is being processed.

Answer (score 0):

[JQuery](http://jquery.com/) is a powerful Javascript library. I think you would find it very helpful if you're wanting to do these types of things with Javascript.

There is a free JQuery plug-in called DataTables which allows you to take a text file as a data source and bind that to a grid.

http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

This may help you do what you want to do. Good luck.